# How can I serialize a self dependent structure with kotlin kotlinx serialization?

Tags: kotlin, serialization

I have some metadata about db objects which I would like to send over the wire, including the id of some row. Since kotlin offers Json serialization out of the box I am quite willing to use that. 
Now the problem is that the type of the ID may be any type, actually for now just Int, Long or UUID. Now I have metadata which describes the type of the key, so on both sides I can provide a (de-)serializer. 
So I have:

```
@file:ContextualSerialization(MetaData::class, Any::class)
package com.example

sealed class MetaProperty(val name:String, val type: KClass<*>) {
    abstract fun serializer() : KSerializer<Any>
}
class IntProperty(name:String) : MetaProperty(name, Int::class) {
    override fun serializer(): KSerializer<Any> = IntSerializer as KSerializer<Any>
}

class MetaData(val type:String, val idType:MetaProperty)

@Serializable
data class DBRelation(
        val from:MetaData,
        val fromId: Any,
        val to:MetaData,
        val toId:Any)
```

Now I just want to serialize Relation, actually in my case only the to-side of the relation (the from is not necessary) I just included it to make serialization possible.
I wrote a naive implementation of a custom serializer:

```
@Serializer(forClass = DBRelation::class)
object RelationToSerializer : KSerializer<DBRelation> {
    lateinit var meta : (String) -> MetaData
    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor = object : SerialClassDescImpl("relation") {
        init {
            addElement("from")            
            addElement("to")
            addElement("fromId")
            addElement("toId")
        }
    }

    @ImplicitReflectionSerializer
    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, obj: DBRelation) {
        val comp = encoder.beginStructure(descriptor)
        comp.encodeStringElement(descriptor, 0, obj.from.type)
        comp.encodeSerializableElement(descriptor, 2, obj.from.idType.type.serializer() as KSerializer<Any>, obj.fromId)

    }

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): DBRelation = run {
        var from : String? = null
        var to : String? = null
        var fromId : Any? = null
        var toId : Any? = null
        val dec = decoder.beginStructure(descriptor)
        loop@ while (true) {
            when(val idx = dec.decodeElementIndex(descriptor)) {
                CompositeDecoder.READ_DONE -> break@loop
                0 ->  from = dec.decodeStringElement(descriptor, idx)
                1 -> to = dec.decodeStringElement(descriptor, idx)
                2 -> fromId = dec.decodeSerializableElement(descriptor, idx, meta(from?:throw IllegalStateException()).idType.serializer())
            }
        }
        DBRelation(meta(from!!), fromId!!, meta(to!!), toId!!)
    }
}
```

Now this implementation may or may not work depending on the order in which the fields are deserialized.

So I have two questions:

A. Does somebody know another solution for my problem? One which does not require me to write special Relation classes for each possible combination of Key types?

B. Even better, is there a way to tell the serialiser to hold back the ID value until `from` was deserialised? Or to give me some serialized version of the ID, which I can later (once I have the `from` value`) deserialise?

Comment: Can you decode both IDs as Strings an then parse them to Int, Long or UUID based on MetaData?

Comment: @SpaceBison well it is possible, but I have a feeling it makes the whole System brittle. I could go and provide something like a `asString`/`fromString` method to PropertyMeta, but that means that if anyone ones to have his class serialised or uses an arbitrary complex key, he has also to provide those methods, instead of marking those classes with `@Serilizable`.